# Testing NTLM/Kerberos against a public URL

Tags: authentication, windows, java, kerberos

I am creating a Java open source package that makes it easy to connect with HttpClient 3.1 to resources that are protected by NTLm v1/v2 and Kerberos.

I need to test this tool against real world servers. Are there any publicly available endpoints that are protected by NTLM or Kerberos that I can get a user and password to test against?

Basically I am looking for something like [Browserspy](http://browserspy.dk/password-ok.php) for NTLM/Kerberos. Also a public site using self signed certificates would be helpful for testing.

Comment: Here is a link to the tool i created on github, ill be happy to hear feedback.  https://github.com/DovAmir/httpclientAuthHelper

Comment: There was for a while http://httpbin-ntlm.com/ but that's gone offline now. See https://github.com/shazow/urllib3/issues/242#issuecomment-24180808

Comment: I myself made http://ntlm.herokuapp.com/ but that runs a Ruby implementation of the protocol so it's not ideal for testing. Also, I've forgotten the password!

Comment: Is your Kerberos infrastructure publicly available? If not, you'll only achieve ntlm authentication.

Comment: @ColonelPanic username: `user` and password: anything will work

Answer (score 1):

A bit late to the party but ...

The [freeipa project](https://freeipa.org) has a public demo realm. See [the instructions](https://www.freeipa.org/page/Demo).

```
$ kinit admin@DEMO1.FREEIPA.ORG
Password for admin@DEMO1.FREEIPA.ORG: 
$ klist 
Ticket cache: KEYRING:persistent:1000:1000
Default principal: admin@DEMO1.FREEIPA.ORG

Valid starting       Expires              Service principal
05/09/2019 20:53:50  05/10/2019 20:53:44    krbtgt/DEMO1.FREEIPA.ORG@DEMO1.FREEIPA.ORG
$ klist 
Ticket cache: KEYRING:persistent:1000:1000
Default principal: admin@DEMO1.FREEIPA.ORG

Valid starting       Expires              Service principal
05/09/2019 20:54:21  05/10/2019 20:53:44  HTTP/ipa.demo1.freeipa.org@DEMO1.FREEIPA.ORG
05/09/2019 20:54:21  05/10/2019 20:53:44  HTTP/ipa.demo1.freeipa.org@
05/09/2019 20:53:50  05/10/2019 20:53:44  krbtgt/DEMO1.FREEIPA.ORG@DEMO1.FREEIPA.ORG
```

The http ticket appeared after kinit'ing and visiting https://ipa.demo1.freeipa.org